# MySql Seperate values in one col to many

Tags: mysql

I am retrieving data from mysql db. All the data is one column. I need to separate this into several cols: The structure of this col is as follows:

```
{{product ID=001 |Country=Netherlands |Repository Link=http://googt.com |Other Relevant Information=test }} ==Description== this are the below codes: code 1 code2 ==Case Study== case study 1 txt case study 2 txt ==Benefits== ben 1 ben 2  === Requirements === (empty col) === Architecture === *arch1 *arch2
```

So I want cols like: Product ID, Country, Repository Link, Architecture etc.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on simply parsing out the output of your column, it will depend on the language of choice you are currently using.

However, in general the procedure for doing this is as follows.

1, pull output into string
2, find a delimiter(In you case it appears '|' will do)
3, you have to options here(again depending on language)
  A, Split each segment into an array
    1, Run array through looping structure to print out each section OR use array
       to manipulate data individually(your choice)
  B, In Simple String method, you can either create a new string, or replace all
     instances of '|' with '\n'(new line char) so that you can display all data.

I recommend the array conversion as this will allow you to easily interact with the data in a simple manner.

This is often something done today with json and other such formats which are often stored in single fields for various reasons.

Here is an example done in php making use of explode()

```
$unparsed = "this | is | a | string that is | not: parsed";
$parsed = explode("|", $unparsed);
echo $parsed[2]; // would be a
echo $parsed[4]; // would be not: parsed
```

Comment: Do you mean language like UT8 as this is what format it needs to be in. When I copied the contents of text to notepad++ it automatically put for me the breaklines that I was looking for. What you have mentioned above pls can you give me code to help me. thanks

Comment: By language, I'm implying the programming language of choice, such as JS,C++,php and so on. I will provide an example in php above. There are allot of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I do not need it in a programming language I need the output to be in a table so I can export it to csv. So I only need your help with the sql script above to seperate the values from the single col